# Scala 3 "Module Abstractions" chapter in the book

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am trying to use the 2nd approach ("Module Abstractions") from [the "Opaque Types" chapter](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-opaque-types.html) of the Scala3 book. The code is intended to show how one can make Scala use a logarithmic number representation.

***The problem is that I do not see how the code from the book may be used. For me, it just does not work.***

```
trait Logarithms:

  type Logarithm

  // operations on Logarithm
  def add(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm
  def mul(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm

  // functions to convert between Double and Logarithm
  def make(d: Double): Logarithm
  def extract(x: Logarithm): Double

  // extension methods to use `add` and `mul` as "methods" on Logarithm
  extension (x: Logarithm)
    def toDouble: Double = extract(x)
    def + (y: Logarithm): Logarithm = add(x, y)
    def * (y: Logarithm): Logarithm = mul(x, y)
    // I added
    def myToDouble: Double = extract(x)


object LogarithmsImpl extends Logarithms:

  type Logarithm = Double

  // operations on Logarithm
  def add(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm = make(x.toDouble + y.toDouble)
  def mul(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm = x + y

  // functions to convert between Double and Logarithm
  def make(d: Double): Logarithm = math.log(d)
  def extract(x: Logarithm): Double = math.exp(x) 

// I added
object Logarithms:
  def apply(d: Double) = LogarithmsImpl.make(d)
```

The book says:

> However, this abstraction is slightly leaky. We have to make sure to
> only ever program against the abstract interface `Logarithms` and never
> directly use `LogarithmsImpl`. Directly using `LogarithmsImpl` would make
> the equality `Logarithm = Double` visible for the user, who might
> accidentally use a `Double` where a logarithmic double is expected.

And now I try to use it:

```
$ ~/Downloads/scala3-3.1.3/bin/scala
Welcome to Scala 3.1.3 (14.0.1, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                                                                                                           
scala> :load my/scala/logarithms1.scala
// defined trait Logarithms
// defined object LogarithmsImpl
// defined object Logarithms
                                                                                                                           
scala> import Logarithms.*
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithms(4)
val res0: LogarithmsImpl.Logarithm = 1.3862943611198906
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithms(2)
val res1: LogarithmsImpl.Logarithm = 0.6931471805599453
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithms(4).toDouble
val res2: Double = 1.3862943611198906
                                                                                                                           
scala> Logarithms(4).myToDouble
-- [E008] Not Found Error: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |Logarithms(4).myToDouble
  |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |value myToDouble is not a member of LogarithmsImpl.Logarithm, but could be made available as an extension method.
  |
  |The following import might fix the problem:
  |
  |  import LogarithmsImpl.myToDouble
  |
1 error found
```

In fact, importing LogarithmsImpl does not help much:

```
scala> import LogarithmsImpl.*
                                                                                                                           
scala> import Logarithms.*
                                                                                                                           
scala> val ll: Logarithm = make(4.0)
val ll: LogarithmsImpl.Logarithm = 1.3862943611198906
                                                                                                                           
scala> val lll: Logarithm = make(2.0)
val lll: LogarithmsImpl.Logarithm = 0.6931471805599453
                                                                                                                           
scala> lll+ll
val res0: Double = 2.0794415416798357
                                                                                                                           
scala> extract(lll+ll)
val res1: Double = 7.999999999999998
```

The last line shows that the addition was the traditional floating-point addition rather than the override from the extension.

***What am I missing?***

**UPD** One more problem in the book's code: the line

```
  def add(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm = make(x.toDouble + y.toDouble)
```

should be

```
  def add(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm = make(x.myToDouble + y.myToDouble)
```

or, even better:

```
  def add(x: Logarithm, y: Logarithm): Logarithm =  x + math.log1p(math.exp(y-x))
```

**UPD2** and it looks like the trait and the objects are not companions, a trait is not a class, only classes may be companions.

Answer (score 2):

The most reasonable way of using this abstraction (that I can see) is like so:

```scala
@main
def main = {
  val L = LogarithmsImpl
  doStuffWithLogarithm(L)
}

def doStuffWithLogarithm(L: Logarithms): Double = {
  import L.*
  val a = L.make(1)
  val b = L.make(2)
  a.myToDouble
}
```

The gist of it is that you have to pass some instance of `Logarithms` and use it to access all methods so that the type alias equality doesn't leak.

scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KacperFKorban/4bnxghkMSzaPqn4vvy19QA/1

That's why it's not a great pattern. And why `opaque types` are useful.

Comment: Why did not `Logarithms.apply()` work? How do I fix it?